# OCaml type error (folding)

Tags: ocaml

I'm getting a type error for the following folding and I'm really not sure how I can solve it... Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

```
List.fold_left = (fun acc y -> ((fst acc +1), x)::acc) [(0,0)] [1;2;3]
```

The idea here is getting `[(index,content)]` as return value.
for `[1;2;3]`, it would be `[(3,3);(2,2);(1,1);(0,0)]`.

Comment: Your question is about an error message and you do not even provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has too many errors to even get a type error!

Here are the first few errors I see:

1. The `=` in your code is a comparison operator. Eventually you'd get a type error for this. Most likely you just want to drop the `=`. It's like writing `sin = x` instead of just `sin x`.
2. The identifier `x` is not defined in your code anywhere.
3. Your accumulated value is a list, so you can't apply `fst` to it.

After you fix these you might start to get type errors :-)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I have long way to go. umm... x should be y and (bad typo..) "=" can be easily fixed. But for (3), I thought that the each element of list is applied to the function so I thought fst could be applied (since the list element is () ). Would it be possible to modify values inside () that is inside a list? Could not find modules to do such a thing besides pst and fst :(

Comment: You can't modify lists or pairs in OCaml. They're immutable. But you can certainly *access* the value you want. If you know the list is never empty (as it never is in your example code) you can use `List.hd` to get the first element, then you can apply `fst` to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two bits of information to the folding procedure:

1. The accumulated list.
2. The next free index.

With this is mind, a possible correction of your function is:

```
let decorate lst =
  List.fold_left (fun (acc, index) y ->  ((y, index)::acc, index+1)) ([],1) lst
  |> fst

# decorate [1; 2; 3];;
- : (int * int) list = [(3, 3); (2, 2); (1, 1)]
```